# AdS, nearly AdS, and asymptotically AdS

Tags: general-relativity, definition, ads-cft, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

Recently, I took a seminar about JT gravity, and the speaker said about exact Ads, nearly Ads, and asymptotically Ads.

**I want to know the difference(i.e., the form of metric? or the conditions on metric) between them and their usage.**

---

What I know about some terminology for asymptotically something is asymptotically flat spacetime. i.e., the curvature vanishes at a large distance.

In terms of metric, $g_{ab} = \eta_{ab} + h_{ab}$, $h_{ab}$ satisfies
\begin{align}
&\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} h_{ab} = \mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{r}) \\
&\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} \partial_{p} h_{ab} = \mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{r^2}) \\
&\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} \partial_{p} \partial_{q} h_{ab} = \mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{r^3}) 
\end{align}
with $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

---

Maybe not all AdS have such geometries; $ads_{2}$ is the special case since the $Ads_{2}$ boundary conditions are not consistent with finite energy excitations due to large long-distance backreactions.

It seems nearly $Ads_{2}$ comes from this which does not die off near the boundaries.

In the arXiv 9911230, I found the definitions of asymptotic ads

[image]